# Toggle between two menu tabs within webpage HTML/Javascript

Tags: javascript, html

I want to toggle between the two tabs that show different graphs. Currently the page opens with the first tab open and you are able to the select the 2nd tab. You cannot re-open the first tab though. I want to be able to freely toggle between the two tabs.

I'm trying to fix something I did not build and with fairly limited knowledge of how it works.

HTML Code is:

```
                <div class="tabsmenuwaste" id="tabsldelay" style="margin-left: auto; margin-right:auto; Margin-top: -50px;">


                    <div id="tab1waste" class="tabheaderwaste" onClick="JavaScript:selectTabwaste(1);">
                        <h4 id="tab1headerwaste" class="active">Daily Summary</h4>
                    </div>

                    <div id="tab2waste" class="tabheaderwaste" onClick="JavaScript:selectTabwaste(2);">
                        <h4 id="tab2headewaster">How's my Business</h4>
                    </div>


                </div>
```

Javascript code is:

```
function selectTabwaste(tabIndex) {

        //Hide All Tabs
        var index = 0;
        var lb = document.querySelectorAll("div.tableauPlaceholderhub").length;


        for (; index < lb; index++) {

            document.querySelectorAll("div.tableauPlaceholderhub")[index].style.display = "none";

            document.querySelectorAll("div.tableauPlaceholderhmb")[index].style.display = "none";

        }

        if (tabIndex == 2) {
            document.getElementById("tab1waste").getElementsByTagName("h4")[0].className = "tabheaderwaste";
            document.getElementById("tab2waste").getElementsByTagName("h4")[0].className = "tabheaderwaste active";

        } else if (tabIndex == 1) {

          document.getElementById("tab1waste").getElementsByTagName("h4")[0].className = "tabheaderwaste active";
            document.getElementById("tab2waste").getElementsByTagName("h4")[0].className = "tabheaderwaste";
        }

        var index = 0;
        var l = document.querySelectorAll("div.tab" + tabIndex + "Contentwaste").length;

        for (; index < l; index++) {

            document.querySelectorAll("div.tab" + tabIndex + "Contentwaste")[index].style.display = "block";

        }

        //Show the Selected Tab
    }
```

I want to be able to freely toggle between the two tabs.

Answer (score 1):

use this code.

```js
'use strict';

let tab = document.getElementsByClassName('tab'),
  tabContent = document.getElementsByClassName('tab-item-content'),
  selector = document.querySelector('.selector'),
  tabs = document.querySelector('.tabs');

function hideTabsContent(a) {
  for (let i = a; i < tabContent.length; i++) {
   tabContent[i].classList.remove('active');
   tab[i].classList.remove('active-item');
  }
 }

selector.style.width = (tab[0].offsetWidth + 'px');

tabs.addEventListener('click', function () {
 let target = event.target;
 if (target.className === 'tab') {
  for (let i = 0; i < tab.length; i++) {
   if (target === tab[i]) {
    showTabsContent(i);
    selector.style.left = (target.offsetLeft + 'px');
    selector.style.width = (target.offsetWidth + 'px');
    break;
   }
  }
 }
});


function showTabsContent(b) {
 hideTabsContent(0);
 tab[b].classList.add('active-item');
 tabContent[b].classList.add('active');
}
```

```css
@import url('https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Ubuntu');

*{
 margin: 0;
 padding: 0;
}
body{
 font-family: 'Ubuntu', sans-serif;
 background: #6395ed;
 padding-top: 40px;
}
#horizontal-tabs{
 max-width: 600px;
 display: block;
 margin: 0 auto;
}
.tabs{
 display: inline-flex;
 justify-content: flex-start;
 align-items: center;
 list-style: none;
 background-color: #bfd3f8;
 color: #fff;
 font-weight: 400;
 border-radius: 7px;
 width: content-box;
 position: relative;

}
.tab{
 display: block;
 padding: 11px 20px;
 position: relative;
 z-index: 99999;

}
.tab:hover{
 cursor: pointer;
}

.selector{
 display:inline-block;
 position: absolute;
 left:0;
 top:0;
 height: 40px;
 z-index:99999;
 border-radius:7px;
 transition: all 500ms cubic-bezier(0.080, -0.195, 0.140, 0.970);
 background: #92b4f2;
}

.selector:after{
 content:'';
 position: absolute;
 z-index: -1;
 left: calc(50% - 10px);
 bottom: -10px;
 width: 0;
 height: 0;
 border-style: solid;
 border-width: 10px 10px 0 10px;
 border-color: #92b4f2 transparent transparent transparent;
}
.tab-content .tab-item-content{
 background: #ffffff;
 border-radius: 10px;
 box-sizing: border-box;
 display: none;
}

.tab-content .tab-item-content.active{
 padding: 20px;
 height: 200px;
 display: block;
}

li.tab .hidden-tab-name{
 font-size: 0;
 visibility: hidden;
 opacity: 0;
 transition: visibility 0s, opacity 0.5s linear;
}
li.tab.active-item .hidden-tab-name{
 display: inline;
 visibility: visible;
 opacity: 1;
 font-size: inherit;
}
```

```html
<section class="tabs-section">
  <div id="horizontal-tabs">
    <ul class="tabs">
      <div class="selector"></div>
      <li class="tab active-item">Tab 1</li>
      <li class="tab">2</li>
      <li class="tab"><span class="hidden-tab-name">Hidden name </span>3</li>
      <li class="tab">4 [special long name]</li>
    </ul>
    <div class="tab-content">
      <div id="item1" class="tab-item-content  active">// Some content(1)</div>
      <div id="item2" class="tab-item-content">// Some content (2)</div>
      <div id="item3" class="tab-item-content">// Third Slide</div>
      <div id="item4" class="tab-item-content">// Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Accusamus corporis deserunt expedita magni nemo numquam qui quidem quisquam rerum voluptate.</div>
    </div>
  </div>
</section>
```

Comment: I'll need to look into this. Not sure how to apply it to amend my existing code. Not sure which are the key parts to take from this.